# shared variables between different source files in c

Tags: c, variables, shared, extern

i have tried sharing a global variable between different source files in c using extern.
it seems like each program creates locally different copies of the variable and as a result, when a program changes its value which also changes is not visible to the second program..how can i repair this? The program is given below:

tools.h

```
#ifndef  __TOOLS__
#define  __TOOLS__
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern int i;

void init();

#endif
```

tools.c

```
#include "tools.h"
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int i;

void init(){

i=0;
}
```

prog1.c

```
#include "tools.h"
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){

i=1;
printf("%d\n", i);

return 0;
}
```

prog2.c

```
#include "tools.h"
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){

sleep(1);
printf("%d\n", i);

return 0;
}
```

prog1 printed 1

prog2 printed 0 (the target was to print 1 - see the change to the value prog1 did)

Comment: Your program has undefined behaviour, since it defines `main` twice.

Comment: If you created two executables, one using `prog1.c` and the other using `prog2.c`, then both programs are behaving normal. If you used both of them, you should get a linker error.

Answer (score 5):

The C language describes the behaviour of *one* program. You seem to have multiple *different* programs. Different programs don't interact with one another other than explicitly through the I/O system (`FILE*`) or the system interface, in a platform-dependent manner (e.g. shared memory on System-V).

Answer (score 1):

The scope of a global variable is limited to a single application/executable.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't how computers work.

Since you show two different `main` functions, I'm going to assume that `prog1` and `prog2` are two separately compiled executables.

In all modern operating systems, programs are prohibited from accessing memory outside of their own designated space.  This is dicated by the operating system, and enforced by any number of features on the CPU.

Typically, each process runs in its own *virtual address space*. That means I can't write a program that directly modifies the memory of my `notepad.exe`. This is a critical feature that allows systems to be as stable as they are today.

If you want to share information between to separate running programs, or even two instances of the same program, (these are all separate *processes*), you'll need to implement some kind of [Inter-Process Communication (IPC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

Comment: This is very misleading. Even if all programs ran directly in physical memory, they still wouldn't be sharing the variable `i` in question. (The linker and loader would just have to work differently to support such a platform.)

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't know about "misleading", because I'm emphasizing the fact that one way or another (paged virtual memory, segmentation, etc.), programs are not allowed to stomp on each other, as dictated by the OS and enforced by the CPU.

Comment: But that's completely incidental. You don't need (to know about) virtual memory, paging, segmentation or RMS's favourite tie colour to explain the OPs situation. The C language suffices.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anywhere in prog1 or prog2 where you call tools' `init` method.. So the fact that it's printing 0 in prog2, is probably just whatever the compiler initialized it to.

Also, if you're compiling these as two separate programs, it will never do what you want.  For that, you need to look into "shared memory" or "IPC" systems, to allow two simultaneously running programs to share data at runtime.

Comment: `i` is global, so it has to be `0` by default.